# Removing the background from an image using C#

Tags: c#, image

i am trying to create an application that remove the background of an image on a click of a button, can anyone give me any direction on how to build it.

the photos are like passport photos i need to remove the white background from them

i am a beginner C# developer and i could use all the help :)

Comment: What do you mean by remove the background? Such as having a picture of a family at the beach and removing the sand, sea and sky etc?

Comment: You're going to need to give a lot more detail. What kind of image? what kind of background? A small set of images, or any images?

Comment: well they are like passport photo i need to remove the white background from it

Comment: It would be nice to know more properties about this image. What format? Does it have layers? Is the background only a fill of a specific color? If the "background" of the image is not simple, this will be a complicated procedure, because we would need to algorithmically find and change the pixels of what you would consider the "background of the image".

Answer (score 0):

You can implement an edge detection algorithm, and have that scan the image. Then start in the upper-left and upper-right corners of the picture, and turn every pixel transparent until you meet and edge, where you stop.

That should keep you from making people's teeth and eyes disappear. White hair might be out of luck.